# Removing the right sided blank column from a ListView in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, markup

I am having trouble removing the blank space (or extra column?) from my ListView looking like following:
[image]

There seems to be no functional workaround solutions from previous questions on the subject at hand. Is it possible to do purely in XAML?

My XAML for the ListView lying within a Grid:

```
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>

        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
        </Style>

<ListView
    Name="lstMovies"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMovie, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionChanged="lstMovies_SelectionChanged"
    SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <!--  COLUMN WIDTHS FITTED WITH AUTO AND MEASURED WITH PowerToys  -->
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="235"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}"
                    Header="Title" />
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="65"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Genre}"
                    Header="Genre" />
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="76"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RunningTime}"
                    Header="Running Time" />
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="109"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Instructor}"
                    Header="Instructor" />
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="93"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PremiereDate}"
                    Header="  Premiere Date  " />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View> </ListView>
```

Comment: You have to live with that(it's normal behaviour of this control) or resize column dynamically to take whole space...

Comment: More annoying is your horizontal alignment... String should be aligned to left, numbers and dates (especially those funny american's ones) to right... You could leave genre centered... But this is just a matter of taste

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for the heads up - useful for a beginner. What is the cause of the 'issue' though? Why does it even appear at all?

Comment: It's normal, not an issue [it always has this - example from my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mel6a.png)

Comment: @Selvin That's why I emphasized the word in ' '. Anyways, thanks for the answer.